# Core Plot Graphs : X axis Label Truncation Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

As shown in the image, X-axis Labels are being truncated.

I am trying with this

```
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.05)]
```

but still I am not able to succeed. Please let me know if any method to avoid this truncation.

This configures graph,

```
-(void)configureGraph {

        CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];
        self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

        graph.paddingLeft = 0;
        graph.paddingRight = 0;
        graph.paddingTop = 0;
        graph.paddingBottom = 0;

        CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        borderLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
        borderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = borderLineStyle;

        CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        titleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
        titleStyle.fontName = [UIFont flukeFontBoldName];
        titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
        graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
        graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
        graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -15.0f);

        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:kPaddingLeft];
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:kPaddingBottom];
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingTop:kPaddingTop];
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingRight:kPaddingRight];

        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
        plotSpace.delegate = self;
}

-(void)configureAxes
{
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

    // Grid line styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.6] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
    x.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
    x.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
    x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 4;
    x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 1;

    // pin axis to bottom
    x.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

    // Y axis
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(20.0f);
    y.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
    y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = kCorePlotYAxisPreferredTickLocationCount;
    y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;

    // Pin axis to left
    y.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
}
```

[image: Graph Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some combination of the following things. Which one(s) you choose depends on the appearance you want to achieve.

- Increase the length of the `xRange` further to move the last data value in from the right edge.
- Increase the right padding on the plot area frame to move the edge of the plot area further from the edge of the graph where the text is being clipped.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your suggestions but increase in right padding not working, i mean either decrease or increase doesn't result in any changes/effect.. are we missing anything here in order to make padding to work...

Comment: One more query, is there any way to decrease font size for X-axis labels.?

Comment: Use a different `labelTextStyle` to change the size, color, or other style properties of the label text. Please edit the question and add your setup code so we can see where the padding is being applied so we can offer suggestions.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question about the graph config part.

Comment: I don't see the axis text styles being set anywhere. Change the `labelTextStyle` to reformat the axis labels.

Comment: You don't show what value `kPaddingRight` has. Make it bigger to move the right edge of the plot area inside the edge of the graph more.

Answer (score 0):

At xAxis, you can set label alignment to left.